# How to find local minimum of differentiation of a function using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, derivative, fminsearch

I have an exercise that uses Matlab to program a function to approximate a solution of function using fixed-point iteration method and a tolerance. However, I'm getting stuck at calculate the local minimum of first differentiation of a function. I've search and found two function in Matlab:

- diff: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/diff.html
- fminbnd: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html

But I can't combine them to solve my problem.
For example, I define f.m file

```
function y = f(x)
    y = 2-1/x;
end
```

These command worked:

```
syms x
diff(f(x)'')
fminbnd(@f, 2, 4)
```

but I don't know how to pass `diff(f(x)'')` to `fminbnd`.

Any help, please.

Thanks!

Comment: Read here: http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html. Actually, why do you think you should be able to pass a derivative to `fminbnd`? Or are you trying to minimise the derivative?

Comment: Thanks. My exercise require an parameter that is the minimum of first derivatives. Now I can using them. But now I get another trouble when trying to use diff in *.m file :v